# Rename files with spaces in path

Tags: python

I've a folder called "True Detective"

```
import shutil
file = "true.detective.s01e04.720p.hdtv.x264-killers.mkv"
dest = "/home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series/True Detective/"
shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

It says:

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series/True Detective/'
```

Folder "/home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series/True Detective/" exists.

When I set a folder with no spaces everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do show the **full** traceback of your exceptions. I am reasonably sure what goes wrong here, but a full traceback would confirm the issue.

Comment: Sorry I'll do it from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination directory must exist for `shutil.copy()` to work; `os.path.isdir(dest)` must be `True`. If `dest` does not exist, `shutil` ends up trying to copy the source filename to the directory name (including the trailing `/`) and that is what raises the exception.

You can call [`os.makedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to ensure that the destination directory is created properly first:

import shutil
   import os

```
file = "true.detective.s01e04.720p.hdtv.x264-killers.mkv"
dest = "/home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series/True Detective/"
try:
    os.makedirs(dest)
except OSError:
    # destination directory already exists
    pass
shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

Comment: The folder already exist (I've updated the question). I've also run your code and it generates two "True Detective" folders. "ls /home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series/True*" give me two folders with the "apparent" same name. Probably the reason is that python codec the space in a different way, because Linux doesn't allow two folders with the same name.

Comment: @alasarr: If a **second** folder is created, then the name doesn't match the first one due to some unicode character difference, which is exactly the issue my answer addresses. What does `os.listdir(u'/home/sharefolder/things/Videos/Series')` show for those two directories?

Comment: Yes, it showed both directories. It happened because the folder was created via SFTP, I don't know if it was the SFTP server itself or Filezilla. Anyways, I just rename the folder doing an mv and everything works fine. Thanks a lot for the help :)